# Adobe string to Javascript object

Tags: javascript, adobe

im doing this all through adobe's extend tool kit and i dont have access to JSON which i'd use stringify and parse

i need to be able to read a file which comes in as a string and convert it to an object and spit it back out

the data that gets read in looks like this and needs to be spit out like this in order for my python script that also reads these files to eval it back to a dictionary

```
data = '{"Other": 0.003986666666136848, "last": {"project": "0414_007_Breakdance_Sample_CINEMATIC", "time": 1400678804.523}, "0414_007_Breakdance_Sample_CINEMATIC": 0.00026972221003638376}'
```

obviously(maybe not) it needs to convert to this:

```
data = {"Other": 0.003986666666136848, "last": {"project": "0414_007_Breakdance_Sample_CINEMATIC", "time": 1400678804.523}, "0414_007_Breakdance_Sample_CINEMATIC": 0.00026972221003638376}
```

which just doesn't have the single quotes

i'm not sure how to go about doing this unless i create my own function that seperates and puts it back to an object and yadda yadda

thanks

Comment: what do you mean you don't have access to JSON? just put its source code (//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/json2/20130526/json2.min.js) at the top of your file. will be way easier than trying to do this by hand.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If I understood correctly, and you can't use `JSON.parse`, use `eval`:

```
var data = '{"Other": 0.003986666666136848, "last": {"project": "0414_007_Breakdance_Sample_CINEMATIC", "time": 1400678804.523}, "0414_007_Breakdance_Sample_CINEMATIC": 0.00026972221003638376}'
data = eval('(' + data + ')');
```

Comment: wow i would have never thought to put () around it. do you know why that makes it work?

Comment: Otherwise the object literal would be parsed as a block, and you'd get a syntax error.